# Online Re-Indexing In SQL Server 2005/2008 Standard

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, index

**The Story:** Once a week, we run a special Maintenance Plan that involves re-indexing 2 critical tables that have ~6 Million records between the two of them. We use SQL Server 2005 Standard Edition.

**The Issue:** During this re-indexing (~15 min operation), we fail to insert data into the tables, and our clients are dataless.

I was told that SQL Server 2008 Enterprise has a "Online Re-Indexing" that is not present in lesser versions of SQL Server that will resolve our problems.

However, I just found the following option in our Maintenance Plan options (SQL 2005 Standard):

[image: SQL 2005 Online Re-Indexing]

**My Question:** Does this perform that same "Online Re-Indexing" that 2008 Enterprise does? What are the repercussions (performance wise) to enabling this option? Was I almost wooed into purchasing a 2008 Enterprise license needlessly?

Comment: The GUI doesn't necessarily know what features you have available in your specific version...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The option is in SSMS but it will not work. SSMS is not Edition smart so to speak, they did not make it smart enough to hide options specific to the Edition you are running.

If you try to use it, I believe it just gives you a message relating to "this is an Enterprise only feature"; or something close to it.